# Forgot to set bash as terminal before uninstalling fish

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal, fish

Well, as dumb as it sounds, I was having some trouble with Fish, and decided to uninstall it. The ***wrong*** way. I simply used `apt-get remove fish` without using `chsh -s /bin/bash` beforehand.

So this is now what happens:

- Terminal may open, but will hang with a blinking cursor.
- PS1 will never show.
- Closing Terminal will log out the current user.
- Installing another Terminal emulator does not resolve this as those hang as well.

I'm on the latest version of Freya. How I got to this point is that I discovered that Fish had problems customizing the prompt when using `fish_config` on debian versions of it, so it was recommended to uninstall the debian version and use a different one in order to fix this issue. So this is where I uninstalled it without remembering to set bash as the default Terminal.

Where can I go from here without completely restoring Elementary OS?

Comment: I have run into this issue. I'm unable to find a solution. Instead of fish, it is zsh for me.

Answer (score 3):

- Launch Ubuntu Software Center
- Reinstall fish
- Launch terminal and change shell to bash: `chsh -s /bin/bash`
- remove fish

Answer (score 2):

The login shell of a user is defined in /etc/passwd. You should edit the file with root privilege and change your user's shell path to /bin/bash.